# Include matrix in equation in R function documentation

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen, roxygen2

I would like to typeset a matrix in an equation in the context of documenting an R function. As a matter of fact, `amsmath` isn't available for R documentation per default and `eqnarray` doesn't work because `\deqn` already opens a corresponding math environment.

So, how do the pro's do it? Via `tabular` or some such?

Comment: From the manual (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Mathematics): `Note that only basic LaTeX can be used, there being no provision to specify LaTeX style files such as the AMS extensions.`

Comment: Yep, I know, that's why I wrote that it isn't available. But since there was nothing like "you shall never write matrix equations into your documentation", I suppose (and hope) that there in fact /is/ a way.

Comment: Rather than trying to shoehorn this piece of the documentation into the very limiting help file format, it might be better to just write a vignette (even a very short one), which you can then reference from the help file.

Comment: You're probably right. I was hoping that there was a designated way to do what I wanted but if there wasn't, then "shoehorning" a matrix into the documentation would likely only clutter up the textual help (which is possibly the reason why there is no such option).